# Can't find what controls the space between my main_list

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

Trying to get my nav bar links to be spread out equally and move further to the left or right. The navbar was a reactive copy and paste nav I found online, only because this is my first time building any kind of website. I've slowly started to under the code of how it works but I'm having a hard time controlling the spacing. Can't find what controls the space between the main_list. or where the padding is located within the code to get it closer to the outer screen.

https://codepen.io/daddchamploo/pen/ZEWNvXN

```css
/* IMPORTS */

@font-face {
  font-family: "Microgramma W05 Bold Extended";
  src: url("Fonts/5098213/0b230448-6101-4794-9ea9-f219c1a8ca3f.woff2") format("woff2"), url("Fonts/5098213/efd98fb1-2129-4b9a-bc42-293757c7b859.woff") format("woff");
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(27, 27, 29);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.li {
  font-family: 'Michroma', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}


/* Navbar section */

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

div.logo {
  width: 180px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Microgramma W05 Bold Extended";
}

div.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: white;
}

.nav div.logo a:hover {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

div.main_list {
  width: 600px;
  height: 65px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Michroma;
  src: url(Michroma.ttf), url(san-serif.ttf);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav div.main_list ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li {
  width: 120px;
  height: 65px;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav div.main_list ul li a:hover {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

.nav div.media_button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 12px;
  display: none;
}

.nav div.media_button button.main_media_button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  ;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav div.media_button button.main_media_button span {
  width: 98%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav div.media_button button.main_media_button:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.nav div.media_button button.main_media_button:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 0.4s;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.nav div.media_button button.main_media_button:hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.nav div.media_button button.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav div.media_button button.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}

.nav div.media_button button.active span:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav div.media_button button.active:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 20deg);
}

.nav div.media_button button.active:hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -20deg);
}


/* Home section */

.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Media query section */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav div.logo {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .nav div.main_list {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .nav div.show_list {
    height: 200px;
  }
  .nav div.main_list ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .nav div.main_list ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  .nav div.main_list ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: table;
  }
  .nav div.media_button {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Michroma;
  src: url(Michroma.ttf), url(san-serif.ttf);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="daddicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dadd1.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Michroma&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo" id="navlogo">
        <a href="#">DADD</a>
      </div>
      <div class="main_list" id="mainListDiv">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MIXING</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="media_button">
        <button class="main_media_button" id="mediaButton">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <footer>
      <p>D.R.E.A.M. LLC</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--image-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read up on [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: Flexbox is a good solution for this, agreed. But li element styling needs to be understood first :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that part of your code you can make this:

```
.nav div.main_list ul li{
    width: 120px;
    height: 65px;
    margin: auto 2rem; /* That will define a equal space between the <li> elements */
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it more than you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
#mainListDiv li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Makes it look like this:

[image: Nav]

You can also add padding, margin, etc to your desires in that selector.

Comment: However, the word shop is still slightly separated. Working to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add margin on the left or the right of your `li`'s.
Css would look something like this:

```
.nav div.main_list ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  Thank you.

Comment: If this works for you please accept the answer as correct.  Glad to help.

Comment: Been pretty busy, sorry.